# Using age as response variable in survival analysis

Tags: survival

I am trying to determine the state of a patient based on his age. the patient can be in one of three possible states (i.e., good, intermediate and bad). I have data on 2000 different patients including patient state, age and other covariates.

My purpose is to determine the probability that a patient is in state i given his age. I think multi-state survival is suitable in my case since I have three states but I don't have data on the duration that each patient spend in each state.

My question is: Can I use multi-state survival analysis for my data? If no, can I manipulate the data so that it become suitable for survival analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Survival analysis is used to model the time it takes for a certain event to occur from a defined starting point.

So say that you had a group of people in good status and you were interested in how long it took them to develop an intermediate or bad status, survival analysis might be a useful approach. But if your "purpose is to determine the probability that a patient is in state i given his age" *at a particular point in time*, then survival analysis is not appropriate.

For a simple good/not-good distinction, [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) would provide a way to estimate the probability as a function of age and other covariates. For three classes (good, intermediate, bad), a form of [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still confused about the use of age as the response variable in survival analysis. for example, if my purpose is to determine how long it took patients to develop an intermediate or bad status. Then can I use the age as response variable or should I have data on the duration (sojourn time) that each patient spend in certain state before he enter the next state? Thank you

Comment: @StatisticQuestions survival analysis needs a defined starting point of time=0. So if you use age as the response variable then you are modeling the time since birth of an event. That might or might not make sense for an application. Furthermore, unless you are using time-dependent covariates, the covariate control values should be those at time 0, or at birth with age as the response variable. A multi-state model can handle good/intermediate/bad progression, but then you should know the age at which each progression happened. Logistic or ordinal regressions seem better for your data.